# Options menu on ICS with ActionBar sherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-optionsmenu

My original application was written for Android 2.1. Afterwards, I've added compatibilty library and ActionBar Sherlock.
Now, I would like to present options menu as overflow in the action bar and it works as expected. However, on devices without menu button, I still get default menu bar at the bottom of the screen. Clicking on it opens the options menu from the action bar. See image below:
[image]

What is worse, this bar shows even on activities that have no options menu defined. 
[image: Activity without options menu]

Regarding my relevant code, there is nothing special about it.
Inflating options menu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

main_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_flag" android:title="@string/I_STR_LANGUAGE" android:id="@+id/menu_lang" android:showAsAction="never"></item>
    <item android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_pin_change" android:title="@string/change_pin" android:id="@+id/menu_pin_change" android:showAsAction="never"></item>
     <item android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_about" android:id="@+id/menu_about" android:title="@string/about_application" android:showAsAction="never"></item>
    <item android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_exit" android:id="@+id/menu_logout" android:title="@string/I_CLOSE" android:showAsAction="never"></item>
</menu>
```

Application theme inherits from DarkActionBar Sherlock Theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Is there a way to hide system menu bar? Can options menu be presented only from action bar? Can it at least be hidden for activites without options menu?

[UPDATE:]  `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />`

Comment: How did you define your "uses-sdk" node in the Manifest ?
On a side note, having a "close" option is not such a good idea, it is recommended to rely only on the back button and the related "onBackPressed" method ...

Comment: Don't worry, "Close" does not exit the application, it just performs logout to the main screen. I've updated my question.

Comment: Cool, just wanted to be sure ;) See my answer for the menu button issue, I think it should solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your uses-sdk node to target the latest API, like so :

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="18"/>
```

Comment: Can't believe the solution was so simple :D Thank you